# Strange thing happening with drag and drop on finder

Tags: macos

I have a Mac OS X 10.7.5. Sometimes, when drag-and-drop-ing files on the Finder, a strange thing happens, i.e. the file I'm dealing with "sticks to the cursor" and releasing the trackpad button has no effect, whereas it should let the file be transferred or copied. Btw I've been dealing with this many times, and for a long time, and have just found out today that tapping the trackpad with two fingers eliminates this strange thing, therefore placing the dragged file in the directory the cursor is on, or copying it there if I'm holding the option key. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Does it happens only for the Finder or does it also happens with other drag-and-drop operations ? Your issue looks like a bug of OS X that might be resolved only be restoring/updating your system.

Comment: As far as I know, it only happens in the Finder. Restoring? You mean reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes, but maybe is there an other solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like a macOS bug. If the side effects are still present, try restarting *Finder service* by the following commands:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.Finder
launchctl start com.apple.Finder
```